# Does contiki-ng require extern RTC oscillator/crystal

Tags: contiki-ng

I have custom board based on CC1310F64RHB (32 pin) without external crystal for rtc. It works well with 'normal' CCS and Energia projects. Now, I try to implement contiki-ng on it. SO, I adapt and define new platform and add LD file for different memory map.

And it compile normal (without warnings or errors), but when I upload it to the board he freeze @  platform_init_stage_one() -> oscillators_select_lf_xosc(), and if I comment it out, he freezes on soc_rtc_init().

Any Idea?

Reagrds
Goran